# How to perform pagination in Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

In Tinkerpop 3, how to perform pagination? I want to fetch the first 10 elements of a query, then the next 10 without having to load them all in memory. For example, the query below returns 1000,000 records. I want to fetch them 10 by 10 without loading all the 1000,000 at once.

```
g.V().has("key", value).limit(10)
```

#### Edit

A solution that works through `HttpChannelizer` on Gremlin Server would be ideal.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From a functional perspective, a nice looking bit of Gremlin for paging would be:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').fold().as('persons','count').
               select('persons','count').
                 by(range(local, 0, 2)).
                 by(count(local))
==>[persons:[v[1],v[2]],count:4]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').fold().as('persons','count').
               select('persons','count').
                 by(range(local, 2, 4)).
                 by(count(local))
==>[persons:[v[4],v[6]],count:4]
```

In this way you get the total count of vertices with the result. Unfortunately, the `fold()` forces you to count all the vertices which will require iterating them all (i.e. bringing them all into memory).

There really is no way to avoid iterating all 100,000 vertices in this case as long as you intend to execute your traversal in multiple separate attempts. For example:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').range(0,2)
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').range(2,4)
==>v[4]
==>v[6]
```

The first statement is the same as if you'd terminated the traversal with `limit(2)`. On the second traversal, that only wants the second two vertices, it not as though you magically skip iterating the first two as it is a new traversal. I'm not aware of any TinkerPop graph database implementation that will do that efficiently - they all have that behavior.

The only way to do ten vertices at a time without having them all in memory is to use the same `Traversal` instance as in:

```
gremlin> t = g.V().hasLabel('person');[]
gremlin> t.next(2)
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
gremlin> t.next(2)
==>v[4]
==>v[6]
```

With that model you only iterate the vertices once and don't bring them all into memory at a single point in time.

Some other thoughts on this topic can be found in this [blog post](https://medium.com/@jayanta.mondal/the-curious-case-of-pagination-for-gremlin-queries-d6fd9518620).

Comment: Thanks Stephen, the last solution sounds good. However, how would you do it if you're using an `HttpChannelizer`?

Comment: If you are doing HTTP, you can't. You would have to switch to websockets and then you get that streaming for free, or if you wanted to control it more manually you could use a session.

Comment: Is it possible in python to save traversal for subsequent multiple iterations by `.next()` step?

In java (as I understand for janus-graph) it can be done by using of session for queries so that - create session
`Client client = cluster.connect("uniqueSessionName",true);`
, define traversal variable  by one query (e.g. `t = g.V().hasLabel('person');`) and iterate over that traversal in other query  (e.g. `t.next(2))`

But how it can be done for pythongremlin?

Comment: there is no `connect()` option in python but you can construct a "session" request message yourself and send that via `Client.submit()`. the format for that message is [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/dev/provider/#_session_opprocessor) and isn't so different from the standard sessionless form of the message constructed in `submit()` shown [here](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/1041f86d2e77d14dc214fdb917c73387987de546/gremlin-python/src/main/jython/gremlin_python/driver/client.py#L113)

Comment: Thanks, Stephen. But, when I'm trying to set `processor = `session` in `            message = request.RequestMessage(  processor='session', op='eval' ...
                      'session': '4ad866cd-def9-4a76-86a1-f788785bb482',
                      'aliases': {'g': self._traversal_source}})`

... I get error  `Exception("Unknown processor")` - as I understand there is no such processor in [serializer.py](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/1041f86d2e77d14dc214fdb917c73387987de546/gremlin-python/src/main/jython/gremlin_python/driver/serializer.py)

Comment: hmm - sorry, i didn't know about that. i guess you'd need to add a processor to the serializer?? i suppose gremlin-python should be modified to support this natively. honestly, it would be better to try to avoid sessions though if you can. they aren't supported cleanly across all graphs so your code becomes less portable for using them. they also come with a bit of overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Why not add `order().by()` and perform `range()` function on your gremlin query.