# Using Union Method of Gremlin Query and its affect on Neptune Transactions

Tags: java, transactions, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

Suppose that I have a graph created on AWS Neptune and I want to get multiple information about a vertex.

I have used the union method to get multiple information via the following query,

```
this.graphTraversalSource.V().hasLabel("label1").hasId("id1")
                .union(__.valueMap(true) ,__.outE().groupCount().by(T.label).unfold(),
                   __.inE("created_post").outV().valueMap(true))
```

Simply, the query is trying to get the following,
 1. attributes of the vertex itself. 
 2. the out-edges and their counts 
 3. the attributes of user who has created the post of id1 The above query returns a

A sample result of the above query on Gremlin-Server would be like this

```
=>{label=label1, id=id1, text=[My sample text]}
==>has_comment=1
==>has_like=1
==>{label=user, id=user1}
```

Now, suppose that I am going to write these in Java, as you know the query must be ended by next() or iterate(). If I typed next(), then the first item in the above result would be returned. `{label=label1, id=id1, text=[My sample text]}` . However, if I tried to use next(4) then I will get the full result. Alternatively, I am aware that I can use `next() and hasNext()` of GraphTraversal to fetch the results as needed without using `next(4)`

I am concerned about the transactions being submitted to Neptune, because according to them

> Transactions Neptune opens a new transaction at the beginning of each
>   Gremlin traversal and closes the transaction upon the successful
>   completion of the traversal. The transaction is rolled back when there
>   is an error.
>
> Multiple statements separated by a semicolon (;) or a newline
>   character (\n) are included in a single transaction. Every statement
>   other than the last must end with a next() step to be executed. Only
>   the final traversal data is returned.
>
> Manual transaction logic using tx.commit() and tx.rollback() is not
>   supported.

According to the above, I understood that each .next() statement will cause a tx to take place at Neptune.

Having said all that, my questions are ,

1. Is my understanding to the transaction techniques of Neptune true ?
2. if yes, does that mean that each time I write `.next()` a transaction will occur ?
3. how does the `.next(int)` behave, for example does using `.next(4)` mean that 4 transaction will take place ?
4. How can I optimize this ? to fetch all needed data using one database access and one transaction ? i.e. is there a better way to accomplish my needs?
5. How can I get all results of the above query using one line ? i.e. not to use hasNext() and next() methods ? is there a way to know the size of the result-set  and thus to use next(result-set-size) method ?

Thanks
Hadi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can terminate the traversal in a variety of ways beyond `next()` and `iterate()` - for example `toList()` grabs all the results and packages them into a `List` object. I'd say that's the most common way people terminate traversals (and easiest to work with), assuming you don't mind realizing a `List` in memory on the client.

Since Neptune uses TinkerPop drivers, I can say that calls to `next()` (or `toList() or other terminators) on bytecode-based traversals will not trigger additional requests to Neptune and therefore not start new transactions. The call to`next()`,`toList()` and other terminating steps operate on data streamed back to the client.

I believe that this portion of the documentation you pointed out:

> Multiple statements separated by a semicolon (;) or a newline character (\n) are included in a single transaction. Every statement other than the last must end with a next() step to be executed. Only the final traversal data is returned.

is related to script based execution and probably doesn't apply based on the fact that you appear to be using bytecode-based traversals.

Comment: How would you achieve running multiple queries in a single transaction using JavaScript bytecode?

Comment: Thank you very much, that was helpful. It seems that you are really aware of the Neptune and Gremlin. What about pagination ? is data streamed to client and we just paginate it ?

Comment: @KfirDadosh each traversal you iterate out (a bytecode request) is a single transaction irrespective of programming language (so including javascript). unless the query can be chained together in a single traversal you can't get multiple queries to execute within a single transaction.

Comment: @HadiAwad i've been working on TinkerPop/Gremlin for about a decade now...i hope i know a few answers :)  pagination is different and is something you would do with Gremlin itself by way of `range()` step. you might find this blog post helpful https://medium.com/@jayanta.mondal/the-curious-case-of-pagination-for-gremlin-queries-d6fd9518620 it's written with cosmosdb in mind but it generally applies to all Gremlin-enabled systems. it even references another answer of mine here on SO you might find useful as well https://stackoverflow.com/q/39826983/1831717