# How Do I Perform Pagination with TinkerPop in Java?

Tags: java, pagination, gremlin, tinkerpop

In Gremlin, we can paginate like this:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').fold().as('persons','count').
               select('persons','count').
                 by(range(local, 0, 2)).
                 by(count(local))
==>[persons:[v[1],v[2]],count:4]
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in Java, but have no idea what `local` is in this case. My current query looks like this:

```
.fold()
.as("persons", "count")
.select("persons", "count")
.by(__.range(0, 2))
.by(__.count())
```

However, it always returns *all* results with a count of 1. How would the pagination be correctly performed in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The details for pagination are described best [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39829597/1831717) but your question seems like it's more about use of `local`. `local` is an value from the enum `Scope` and a [common import](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#java-imports) for all languages Gremlin is implemented in.

```
import static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Scope.local;
```

You can always find out more about the arguments to Gremlin steps by looking at the [javadoc](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversal.html#range-org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Scope-long-long-).

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. It works correctly now after adding it as parameter to `.range(Scope.local, 0, 2)` and `.count(Scope.local)`.