# TinkerPop not getting correct count type with traversal

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I want to retrieve the specific range of users(required for pagination) and want to retrieve the total count as well, I'm executing the below query which is retrieving the list of user vertices as expected but the total count is returned as `BulkSet`

```
Map<String, Object> result = gt.V().hasLabel("user").sideEffect(__.count().store("total"))
    .order().by("name", Order.desc)
    .range(0, 10).fold().as("list")
    .select("list","total").next();
```

The output is as below

[image]

How do I get the correct count as a `Long` value instead of the `BulkSet`?

Comment: am I not suppose to use sideEffect in the query? not sure if this is the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paging with Gremlin is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39829597/1831717) and references [this blog post](https://medium.com/@jayanta.mondal/the-curious-case-of-pagination-for-gremlin-queries-d6fd9518620) which provides additional information on the topic. Those resources should help you with your paging strategy.

You framed this question in terms of inquiring about `BulkSet` so it isn't quite a duplicate of the answer I referenced, so I will try to answer that much for you. `BulkSet` allows for an important traversal optimization in TinkerPop which helps reduce object propagation, thus reducing memory requirements for a particular query. It does this by holding the traverser object and its count where the count is the number of times that object has been added to the `BulkSet`. Calling `size()` or `longSize()` (where the latter returns a `long` and the former returns `int`) will return the summation of the counts and therefore the "correct" or actual count of the objects. A call to `uniqueSize()` will return actual size of the set which will be the unique objects within it.

If you want the size of the `BulkSet` you just need to `count()` it:

```
gt.V().hasLabel("user").sideEffect(__.count().store("total"))
    .order().by("name", Order.desc)
    .range(0, 10).fold().as("list")
    .select("list","total")
      .by().
      .by(count(local))
```

That said, I don't think your traversal isn't really doing what you want . The `sideEffect()` is just counting the current traverser which will simply return "1" and then you store that "1" in the list "total". At least that's what I see with TinkerGraph:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("person").sideEffect(count().store("total")).range(0,1).fold().as('list').select('list','total').by().by(count(local))
==>[list:[v[1]],total:1]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("person").sideEffect(count().store("total")).range(0,10).fold().as('list').select('list','total').by().by(count(local))
==>[list:[v[1],v[2],v[4],v[6]],total:4]
```

Interesting that JanusGraph somehow gives you 114 rather than 10 for the "total". I'd not expect that. I'd consider avoiding reliance on that "feature" in the case it is a "bug" that is later "fixed". Instead, please consider the posts I'd provided and look at them for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks. The posts really helped. I always expect answer from you for my gremlin related questions :)